# Postgresql LOCK TABLE command waits even with NOWAIT

Tags: java, postgresql, jakarta-ee, locking

I have a process(cron job) in my application(JEE). And I have two instances of it running on two different machines.
I want this cron job to be executed only once. I know there are many ways to do this. But I want to do it using database table Lock.

So the first thing that is done in this process is to Get a LOCK on some table in the database. If one process gets the lock, then the other process should immediately abort.

I am using Postgresql(10.4).This is what I have in my code

```
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
statement.execute("LOCK TABLE crontable NOWAIT");
```

With this what I expect is when one process gets a lock then other process will abort(according to the documentation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-lock.html)

But what currently happening is, other process waits till the lock is released by the first process.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Unrelated, to your problem: I think an [advisory lock](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS) would be more suited for this kind of task

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for the advice. I tried this. `SELECT pg_try_advisory_lock(1) from sometable`. This works when I execute this directly on the database. But when I tried from java code(deployed on application server). Both the process gets the lock. Not sure what is wrong. I am using the same id in both the process

Comment: You probably turned on autocommit on the JDBC connection, which means the lock is obtained through the select, then the transaction gets committed and thus the lock is released again

Comment: No. I have explicilty disabled it. `connection.setAutoCommit(false);`

Comment: Then you probably have some other code that does a commit after the select. Maybe an obfuscation layer like Hibernate. Do you use a connection pool?

Comment: No. I am using `PGSimpleDataSource datasource =  new PGSimpleDataSource(); datasource.getConnection()`  https://codeshare.io/50J8xD

Comment: Examine `pg_locks` if you really havd a database lock. The lock may well be in the Java code.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe. Yes I have database lock. What I noticed is with `pg_try_advisory_lock` I see two entries in database. And hence mutual exclusion doesn't work. But if I use `pg_advisory_lock`, and set the `lock_timeout` as 1 second. I can achieve what I want.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. With `pg_try_advisory_lock` what I observed is, when one process excutes and gets the lock. I see three entries created in pg_locks with lock_type relation, virtualxid, and advisory) When another process runs in parallel and tries to get lock. it created two more entries in pg_locks with lock_type as relation and virtualxid. And hence the second process doesn't abort(as I expected). But If I use `pg_advisory_lock` and use `lock_timeout` , then I could achieve what I wanted. Any thoughts why `pg_try_advisory_lock` doesn't work ?